# Single Quotes in PHP Postgres PDO

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo

I'm using the PDO class in PHP to run PostgreSQL queries.

```
$conn = new PDO("pgsql:host=$dbhost;port=$dbport;dbname=$dbname;user=$dbuser;password=$dbpass");
$query = 'SELECT "ID", "Description" FROM "MyTable"';
$result = $conn->query($query);
```

Assume that something in the query needs to be in single quotes like

```
$query = 'SELECT "ID", "Description" FROM "MyTable" WHERE "Description" = 'A107'';
```

This won't work the way it is. However, if I do the following, it will work.

```
$query = 'SELECT "ID", "Description" FROM "MyTable" WHERE "Description" = ' . $conn->quote('A107', PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

I know there are better ways of doing this with PDO's prepare and execute. This code is essentially part of a template which a co-worker of mine (who has limited programming experience) wishes to paste PostgreSQL queries into.

Thus, I'm looking for the easiest way to deal with single quotes in this case. The queries may be more complex than the example I gave and I don't want them to have to mess around with the template too much. Something along the lines of escaping would be nice, but haven't found anything like this that works. I realize that some modifications on their part will be necessary, but would like to minimize this.

Comment: You can escape the single quote - use `\'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to paste any query into php code without concern for escaping the code itself, you can use 'heredoc' or 'nowdoc'. See [php strings documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

It uses a unique tag before and after the string to identify the start and end. Note that the end identifier must be on the start of the line.

```
$query = <<<'a_unique_string'
select * from foo where bar = 'baz'
a_unique_string;
```